# TypeError: Image data can not convert to float

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a 16-bit image like so:

```
import skimage 
import random
from random import randint                        
xrow=raw_input("Enter the number of rows to be present in image.=>")
row=int(xrow)
ycolumn=raw_input("Enter the number of columns to be present in image.=>")
column=int(ycolumn)

A={}
for x in xrange(1,row):
    for y in xrange(1,column):
        a=randint(0,65535)
        A[x,y]=a 

imshow(A)
```

But I get the error `TypeError: Image data can not convert to float`.

Comment: `A` is a dictionary, yet you are assuming that it's an image type for display.  That's why you're getting the `TypeError`.  However, I'm very confused because I don't know which image library you're using.  You've imported `scikit-image` yet you tagged your post as using PIL.  In addition, the `imshow` call is ambiguous because I don't know which package that comes from.  None of your `import` statements makes that clear to me. Please edit your question to address what package `imshow` comes from and which image library you'd like to use for your post. BTW, images are indexed starting at `0`.

Answer (score 60):

This question comes up first in the Google search for this type error, but does not have a general answer about the cause of the error. The poster's unique problem was the use of an inappropriate object type as the main argument for `plt.imshow()`. A more general answer is that `plt.imshow()` wants an array of floats and if you don't specify a `float`, numpy, pandas, or whatever else, might infer a different data type somewhere along the line. You can avoid this by specifying a `float` for the `dtype` argument is the constructor of the object.

See the [Numpy documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

See the [Pandas documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame)

Comment: I have the same issue however I am working with RDD, my code works with python 2 but not with python 3, get the same error 
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
what should I do in this case?
I cannot specify dtype for an rdd

Answer (score 45):

This happened for me when I was trying to plot an imagePath, instead of the image itself. The fix was to load the image, and plotting it.

Answer (score 28):

The error occurred when I unknowingly tried plotting the image path instead of the image.

My code :

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pytesseract
from resizeimage import resizeimage

img = cv.imread("D:\TemplateMatch\\fitting.png") ------>"THIS IS THE WRONG USAGE"
#cv.rectangle(img,(29,2496),(604,2992),(255,0,0),5)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Correction:
`img = cv.imread("fitting.png")` --->THIS IS THE RIGHT USAGE"

Answer (score 24):

First read the image as an array

```
image = plt.imread(//image_path)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: As this is an older question with a lot of answers, could you provide information on why this answer is better than the many before it, some of which contain signficantly more explanation?

Comment: wow, best answer for my problem. Now the question is why `imshow` doesn't have this default behavior when passed a `path`

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting this error, and the answers given above says that we should upload them first and then use their name instead of a path - but for Kaggle dataset, this is not possible.

Hence the solution I figure out is by reading the the individual image in a loop in mpimg format. Here we can use the path and not just the image name.

I hope it will help you guys.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
for img in os.listdir("/content/train"): 
  image = mpimg.imread(path)
  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Putting an import statement in a loop is a very bad habit. I edited it for you.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize it yet but now when you have pointed it out I kinda got the reason why you are saying so. Thank you anyways

Comment: You just need to first read the image, which was the case in my situation. make sure you read the path first. imread(path)

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand of the scikit-image docs (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/index.html), imshow() takes a **ndarray** as an argument, and not a dictionary:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html?highlight=imshow#skimage.io.imshow

Maybe if you post the whole stack trace, we could see that the TypeError comes somewhere deep from imshow().

Answer (score 3):

try

```
import skimage
import random
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xrow = raw_input("Enter the number of rows to be present in image.=>")
row = int(xrow)
ycolumn = raw_input("Enter the number of columns to be present in image.=>")
column = int(ycolumn)

A = np.zeros((row,column))
for x in xrange(1, row):
    for y in xrange(1, column):
        a = randint(0, 65535)
        A[x, y] = a

plt.imshow(A)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this,

```
   plt.imshow(numpy.real(A))
   plt.show()
```

instead of `plt.imshow(A)`

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you may transfer a wrong type to imshow(), for example I use albumentations.Compose to change image, and the result is a dict rather than numpy.ndarray. so just change

`plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(aug(image=img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`

to

`plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(aug(image=img)['image'], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`

then it works.

Comment: This works with albumentations package. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
plt.imshow(im.reshape(im.shape[0], im.shape[1]), cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
```

It would help in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may have this problem in Pycharm. If so, you may try this to your problem.

Go to `File-Setting-Tools-Python Scientific`in Pycharm and remove the option of `Show plots in tool window`.

Comment: nice guess! trying this out

Answer (score 0):

In my case `image path` was wrong! So firstly, you might want to check if image path is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe the image path contains Chinese characters, changing to English characters will solve this question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post important information like code and error messages as images

Comment: Please write the code snippet instead of using images.

Comment: that's not an answer to _this_ question. read the question before answering.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of error try checking file path or name

Comment: Once you've decided to answer for 7+ years olq qustion... you'd better read the previous answers first, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the missing the parenthesis on the squeeze function.

```
plt.imshow(image.squeeze)
```

To solve the problem, add parenthesis to invoke the squeeze function.

```
plt.imshow(image.squeeze())
```

Answer (score -1):

As for cv2 is concerned.

1. You might not have provided the right file type while `cv2.imread()`.
   eg jpg instead of png.
2. Or you are providing image path instead
   of image's array. eg `plt.imshow(img_path)`,

try `cv2.imread(img_path)` first then `plt.imshow(img)` or `cv2.imshow(img)`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that my array was  in type u3 i changed it to float and it worked for me .
I had a dataframe with Image column having the image/pic data.Reshaping part depends to person to person and image they deal with mine had 9126 size hence it was 96*96.

```
a = np.array(df_train.iloc[0].Image.split(),dtype='float')
a = a.reshape(96,96)
plt.imshow(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Input should be array

`plt.imshow(plt.imread('image_path'))`

Answer (score -2):

For an image file in .mat format.
I have done the following to show the image using the imshow() function.

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('point05m_matrix.mat')

x = mat.get("matrix")
print(type(x))
print(len(x))

plt.imshow(x, extent=[0,60,0,55], aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Comment: that's not answering *this* question.