# Open cv 2 wont read images from more then 1 folder?

Tags: python, opencv

I m try to create my own dataset from images and have 2 categories. When I'm using code, only 1 folder from images stays as array 2nd write -Image data cannot be converted to float. What is I'm doing wrong?

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Datadir= 'D:\\mml\\malariya\\'
Categories = ['parazitesone', 'uninfectedone']

for category in Categories:
    path = os.path.join(Datadir, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float` is a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302180/typeerror-image-data-can-not-convert-to-float). The problem is probably because you are trying to load an invalid image. `os.listdir()` also returns directories and those would return `None` from `imread`, leading to the `TypeError`.

I would recommend to check if the `img` is a file and, if you expect your images to be in a given set of extensions, check for that as well. It would look like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

Datadir= 'D:\\mml\\malariya\\'
Categories = ['parazitesone', 'uninfectedone']

for category in Categories:
    path = os.path.join(Datadir, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_fname = os.path.join(path, img)
        # check if is file
        if not os.path.isfile(img_fname):
            print('Skipping: {}'.format(img_fname))
            continue
        # or check for extensions
        if not any([img_fname.endswith(e) for e in ['.png', '.jpg']]):
            print('This file has an unsupported extension: {}'.format(img_fname))
            continue
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        # or check if the return is None
        if img_array is None:
            print('This image could not be loaded: {}'.format(img_fname))
            continue
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
```

Of course, you don't need to use all these `if`. Choose one that matches your needs.