# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (133) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model. I am facing issue while doing the training iteration for my model. The code is as below:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        #convo layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,32,3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32,64,3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64,128,3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128,256,3)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(256,512,3)

        #pooling layer
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)

        #linear layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512*5*5,2048)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2048,1024)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024,133)

        #dropout layer
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        def forward(self, x):
        #first layer
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        #x = self.dropout(x)
        #second layer
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        #x = self.dropout(x)
        #third layer
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        #x = self.dropout(x)
        #fourth layer
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        #fifth layer
        x = self.conv5(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        #x = self.dropout(x)

        #reshape tensor
        x = x.view(-1,512*5*5)
        #last layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x

        #loss func
        criterion = nn.MSELoss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = 0.0001)
        #criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        #optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr = 0.05)

        def train(n_epochs,model,loader,optimizer,criterion,save_path):    
           for epoch in range(n_epochs):
              train_loss = 0
              valid_loss = 0
              #training 
              net.train()
              for batch, (data,target) in enumerate(loaders['train']):
                   optimizer.zero_grad()
                   outputs = net(data)
                   #print(outputs.shape)
                   loss = criterion(outputs,target)
                   loss.backward()
                   optimizer.step()
```

When I use the CrossEntropy Loss function and SGD optimizer, I able able to train the model with no error. 
When I use MSE loss function and Adam optimizer, I am facing the following error:

```
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-20-2223dd9058dd> in <module>
      1 #train the model
      2 n_epochs = 2
----> 3 train(n_epochs,net,loaders,optimizer,criterion,'saved_model/dog_model.pt')

<ipython-input-19-a93d145ef9f7> in train(n_epochs, model, loader, optimizer, criterion, save_path)
     22 
     23             #calculate loss
---> 24             loss = criterion(outputs,target)
     25 
     26             #backward prop

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (133) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 1.
```

Does the selected loss function and optimizer effect the training of the model? Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: what's the size of your input data?

Comment: 'Does the selected loss function and optimizer effect the training of the model?' - Of course it affects the training of the model (i.e. the performance of the model for your task). I think you want to ask whether it requires some change to your model (to make the dimensions compatible).

Comment: @AnubhavSingh torch.Size([10, 3, 224, 224])

Comment: @akshayk07 my question is why is it that I am getting the mentioned runtime error when I use MSE loss function and not when I use CrossEntropy loss function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message clearly suggests that the error occurred at the line

```
loss = criterion(outputs,target)
```

where you are trying to compute the `mean-squared error` between the input and the target.
See this line: `criterion = nn.MSELoss()`.

I think you should modify your code where you are estimating loss between (output, target) pair of inputs,i.e., `loss = criterion(outputs,target)` to something like below:

```
loss = criterion(outputs,target.view(1, -1))
```

Here, you are making `target` shape same as `outputs` from model on line

```
outputs = net(data)
```

One more think to notice here is the output of the `net` model, i.e., outputs will be of shape `batch_size X output_channels`, where batch size if the first dimension of input images as during the training you will get batches of images, so your shape in the forward method will get an additional batch dimension at `dim0`: `[batch_size, channels, height, width`], and `ouput_channels` is number of output features/channels from the last linear layer in the `net` model.

And, the the target labels will be of shape `batch_size`, which is `10` in your case, check `batch_size` you passed in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader()`. Therefore, on reshaping it using `view(1, -1)`, it will be of converted into a shape `1 X batch_size`, i.e., `1 X 10`.

That's why, you are getting the error:

> RuntimeError: input and target shapes do not match: input [10 x 133],
>   target [1 x 10]

So, a way around is to replace `loss = criterion(outputs,target.view(1, -1))` with `loss = criterion(outputs,target.view(-1, 1))` and change the `output_channels` of last linear layer to `1` instead of `133`. In this way, both of `outputs` and `target` shape will be equal and we can compute `MSE` value then.

Learn more about pytorch `MSE` loss function from [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html#loss-function).

Comment: When I change the code you mentioned, I still face the same error. The size of target is now: torch.Size([10, 1]) and output size is torch.Size([10, 133])
The target size is based on the batch_size?

Comment: @user11619814, can you please add full code so that I can try myself?

Comment: So, here the target shape must matches the outputs shape, which is [10, 133] which completely makes sense as as your data shape is [10, 3, 224, 224] and output channels from Net model is 133. That's why [10, 133].

Comment: Actually, I think I now understood what's the problem: change self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024,133) to self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024,1)

Comment: @user11619814, can you please tell me the shape of  (data,target) pair  in enumerate(loaders['train'])

Comment: You can find the code here: https://github.com/gprashmi/Dog_breed_classifier/blob/master/dog_breed_classifier-3.ipynb

Comment: Data shape: torch.Size([10, 3, 224, 224])
target shape: torch.Size([1, 10])

Comment: Can you please tell me if my understanding on target is correct. This target is the number of labels present in the dataset?

Comment: target is the label in the training dataset (in batches) itself.

Comment: By the way have you tried : change self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024,133) to self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024,1)

Comment: To change self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024,133) to self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024,1), isn't the second parameter of last Linear layer equal to number of classes in the dataset? the number of classes in my dataset is 133.

Comment: True but this is the only way you are gonna make `outputs` equals to `target` as `target` is  of shape `[10, 1]` after using `.view(-1, 1)`. How will you convert it into `10x133`, or shape of `outputs`?

Comment: Let me try this once more.

Comment: How there are 133 classes in the dataset ? Are there 133 dog breeds in your dataset ?

Comment: Yes there are 133 dog breeds in my dataset. By modifying the code to this:  target = target.view(target.size(0),-1) print(target.dtype) print(target.shape) target = target.type(torch.FloatTensor), the target type is now same as outputs(float32) and  error was eliminated.

Comment: Can yo please tell me if there is a specific method to calculate the training loss? I came a few formulae while looking for it 1. #calculate training loss  train_loss = train_loss + ((1 / (batch + 1)) * (loss.data - train_loss)) 2. train_loss += loss.item(). Now I am confused as to if there is a way to calculate it?

Comment: This is a MSE loss function:`def mse_loss(input, target):
    return ((input - target) ** 2).sum() / input.data.nelement()`

Comment: Check this for custom loss function: https://spandan-madan.github.io/A-Collection-of-important-tasks-in-pytorch/#SECTION-5---CUSTOM-LOSS-FUNCTIONS

Comment: I have a code for predicting dog breed after training on CNN model,I am getting the class index of the breed and want to display an random image based on the class index folder obtained. When I try to display the random image, I am getting the  error:Image data cannot be converted to float, I have tried displaying through imshow command, but still facing the same error. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Please check this SO solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302180/typeerror-image-data-can-not-convert-to-float

Comment: I have created a question ...with code in it....Can you please have a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862204/image-data-cannot-be-converted-to-float

Answer (score 15):

Well, the error is because the `nn.MSELoss()` and `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` expect different `input`/`target` combinations. You cannot simply change the criterion function without changing the inputs and targets appropriately. From the docs:

[`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss):

> - **Input**:
>
>   - (N, C) where C = number of classes, or
>   - (N, C, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K) with K >= 1 in the case of K-dimensional loss.
> - **Target**:
>
>   - (N) where each value is in range [0, C-1] or
>   - (N, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K) with K >= 1 in the case of K-dimensional loss.

[`nn.MSELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.MSELoss):

> - **Input**:
>
>   - (N,∗) where ∗ means, any number of additional dimensions.
> - **Target**:
>
>   - (N,∗), same shape as the input

As you can see, in the MSELoss, Target is expect to have the same shape as input, while in the CrossEntropyLoss, the `C` dimension is dropped. You cannot use MSELoss as a *drop-in replacement* for CrossEntropyLoss.

Comment: oh okay...so if I want to use MSELoss, then how do I modify my code to get the target shape same as input?

Comment: Well, you need to drop the C dimension. To do that correctly I would need to know what this target is expected to be when using MSE.

Comment: If u mean the size of target, then its torch.Size([1, 10])