# Pytorch Runtime Error - The size of tensor a (5) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, torch, torchvision

I am trying to train a Faster RCNN Network on a custom dataset consisting of images for object detection. However, I don't want to directly give an RGB image as input, I actually need to pass it through another network (a feature extractor) along with the corresponding thermal image and give the extracted features as the input to the FRCNN Network. The feature extractor combines these two images into a 4 channel tensor and the output is a 5 channel tensor. It is this 5 channel tensor that I wish to give as input to the Faster RCNN Network.

I followed the PyTorch docs for Object Detection Finetuning [(link here)](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html) and came up with the following code to suit my dataset.

```py
class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        self.num_classes = 5
        img_rgb_path = os.path.join(self.root, "rgb/", self.rgb_imgs[idx])
        img_thermal_path = os.path.join(self.root, "thermal/", self.thermal_imgs[idx])


        img_rgb = Image.open(img_rgb_path)
        img_rgb = np.array(img_rgb)
        x_rgb = TF.to_tensor(img_rgb)
        x_rgb.unsqueeze_(0)

        img_thermal = Image.open(img_thermal_path)
        img_thermal = np.array(img_thermal)
        img_thermal = np.expand_dims(img_thermal,-1)
        x_th = TF.to_tensor(img_thermal)
        x_th.unsqueeze_(0)       

        print(x_rgb.shape)  # shape of [3,640,512]
        print(x_th.shape) # shape of [1,640,512]

        input = torch.cat((x_rgb,x_th),dim=1) # shape of [4,640,512]


        img = self.feature_extractor(input) #  My custom feature extractor which returns a 5 dimensional tensor

        print(img.shape) # shape of [5,640,512]



        filename = os.path.join(self.root,'annotations',self.annotations[idx])
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        objs = tree.findall('object')

        num_objs = len(objs)
        boxes = np.zeros((num_objs, 4), dtype=np.uint16)
        labels = np.zeros((num_objs), dtype=np.float32)
        seg_areas = np.zeros((num_objs), dtype=np.float32)

        boxes = []
        for ix, obj in enumerate(objs):
            bbox = obj.find('bndbox')
            x1 = float(bbox.find('xmin').text)
            y1 = float(bbox.find('ymin').text)
            x2 = float(bbox.find('xmax').text)
            y2 = float(bbox.find('ymax').text)

            cls = self._class_to_ind[obj.find('name').text.lower().strip()]
            boxes.append([x1, y1, x2, y2])
            labels[ix] = cls
            seg_areas[ix] = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)

        boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        seg_areas = torch.as_tensor(seg_areas, dtype=torch.float32)
        labels = torch.as_tensor(labels, dtype=torch.float32)

        target =  {'boxes': boxes,
                'labels': labels,
                'seg_areas': seg_areas,
                }

        return img,target
```

My main function code is as follows

```py
import utils


def train_model(model, criterion,dataloader,num_epochs):
    since = time.time()

    best_model = model
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.005,
                            momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)


        lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                               step_size=3,
                                               gamma=0.1)

        # optimizer = lr_scheduler(optimizer, epoch)
        model.train()  # Set model to training mode

        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0

        for data in dataloader:
            inputs, labels = data[0][0], data[1]

            inputs = inputs.to(device) 
            # zero the parameter gradients

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward
            outputs = model(inputs, labels)
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()


            running_loss += loss.item()
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels).item()

        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloader)
        epoch_acc = running_corrects / len(dataloader)

        print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
            phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

backbone = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True).features
backbone.out_channels = 1280

anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128, 256, 512),),
                                   aspect_ratios=((0.5, 1.0, 2.0),))

roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=[0],
                                                output_size=7,
                                                sampling_ratio=2)
num_classes = 5

model = FasterRCNN(backbone = backbone,num_classes=5,rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator,box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)

dataset = CustomDataset('train_folder/')
data_loader_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True,collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

train_model(model, criterion, data_loader_train, num_epochs=10)
```

The collate_fn defined in the utils.py file is the following

```py
def collate_fn(batch):
    return tuple(zip(*batch))
```

I, however, get the following error while training

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 147, in <module>
    train_model(model, criterion, data_loader_train, num_epochs)
  File "train.py", line 58, in train_model
    outputs = model(inputs, labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py", line 66, in forward
    images, targets = self.transform(images, targets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/detection/transform.py", line 46, in forward
    image = self.normalize(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/detection/transform.py", line 66, in normalize
    return (image - mean[:, None, None]) / std[:, None, None]
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (5) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

I am a newbie in Pytorch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (133) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783182/runtimeerror-the-size-of-tensor-a-133-must-match-the-size-of-tensor-b-10-at)

Comment: No, my question is about how to provide an input to a FRCNN model where the number of channels is not 3

Answer (score 1):

The backbone network you are using for the FasterRCNN is a pretrained mobilenet_v2.
The input channel of a network is decided by the number of channels of the input data. Since the (backbone) model is pretrained (on natural images?) with 3 channels `3xNxM`, you cannot use it for tensors of dimension `5xPxQ` (skipping the singleton `<batch_size>` dimension).

Basically, you have 2 options,
1. Reduce the output channel dimension of the 1st network to 3 (better if you are training it from scratch)
2. Make a new backbone for the FasterRCNN with 5 channels in input and train it from scratch.

As for explaining the error message,

```py
return (image - mean[:, None, None]) / std[:, None, None]
```

Pytorch is trying to normalize the input image where your input image has dimension `(5,M,N)`  and teh tensors `mean` and `std` have 3 channels instead of 5

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I actually want to keep the 5 channel input for the model. So I would like to go with the 2nd option. For that, I have tried the following
      
`model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False)`  
`model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features=5, num_classes) `   
But despite this, I get the same error. Could you please let me know what to change?

Comment: Though you are not using pretrained model, you are still using resnet50 backbone that still expects 3 channels input. You will have to manually replace the 1st conv payer of the backbone to 6 channels. You can still use a prrtrained model just thatreplace the 1st layer and make it trainable.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I managed to change the input channels to 3. But the issue is actually with the GeneralizedRCNN Transform() which happens before the image is passed through the model. I am not able to understand how do I modify the code for GeneralizedRCNN Transform()

Comment: My code is as follows
`model = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False)`  
`in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features`  
`model.backbone.body.conv1 = Conv2d(5, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2),
 padding=(3, 3), bias=False)`  
`model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features,num_classes)`