# How I can display images in file?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

When I run this, I'm getting this error (below the code)

```
DATADIR =r"C:\Users\Müco\Desktop\YAZILIM\kaggle_deeplearning\cat-dog\PetImages"
CATEGORIES =['Cat','Dog']

for category in CATEGORIES:
path =os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
for img in os.listdir(path):
    img_path =os.path.join(path,img)
    img_arr =cv2.imread(img_path)
    plt.imshow(img_arr,cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    break

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

I also tried to print img_arr to see what might be the problem is.. and I get:

```
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path =os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_path =os.path.join(path,img)
        img_arr =cv2.imread(img_path)
        print(cv2.imread(img_arr))
        break

None
None
```

I don't think my path is wrong or anything like that I've checked couple of times and tried many things..  any idea?

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `neural-network` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Do the answers here resolve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302180/typeerror-image-data-can-not-convert-to-float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. God knows I've tried many things, and finally one of them worked. I still don't know why `cv2.imread( )` doesn't work but I use `plt.imread( )` instead, and it works like a charm. I also want specific image shape(otherwise I'm having problem at further steps, especially when I want to turn them into a numpy array).

```
DATADIR =r"C:\Users\Müco\Desktop\YAZILIM\kaggle_deeplearning\cat-dog\PetImages"
CATEGORIES =['Dog','Cat']
IMG_SIZE =50
data =[]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path =os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    label =CATEGORIES.index(category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            img_path =os.path.join(path,img)
            img_arr =plt.imread(img_path)
            img_arr = cv2.resize(img_arr,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)) 
            if img_arr.shape==(50,50,3):
                data.append([img_arr,label])
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```